# How to make a pseudo element extend to full height?

Tags: css, background-image, pseudo-element

I have a page with the HTML element set to full height:

```
html{
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

My body element contains a repeating background image as a pseudo element:

```
body:before{
        content: "";
        border:2px solid blue;
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        background: url("https://website.com/uploads/background-repeat.png") repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;}
```

Inside the body I have a `#wrapper` element where all the contents of my SPA live:

```
<body id="gradient">

    <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header" />
        <div id="content" />
        <div id="footer" />  ...
        </div>
```

However my `body` element does not expand with the wrapper's contents. How do make the background alway show whilst the user scrolls down the page instead  of stopping at the first fold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` not taking auto height because you are restricting its height to 100%. So just give `min-height:100%` and `height: auto;`.
Also you can directly give `background` to `body` no need of pseudo elements.

```
html {
   height: 100%;
}
body{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   min-height: 100%;
   background: url("https://website.com/uploads/background-repeat.png") repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change `body:before` to `body` the image will repeat just fine:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150") repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1,
p {
  color: #333;
}

#wrapper,
#content,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Background Stuff &amp; Things</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis porttitor quis justo vitae suscipit. Aliquam ac felis eleifend, pharetra turpis malesuada, mattis odio. Morbi semper diam id est vestibulum, non pulvinar
      diam faucibus. Fusce dolor tortor, viverra eget malesuada sit amet, posuere sed tellus. Sed aliquet condimentum est, at finibus justo interdum a. Nam vel justo urna. Donec id magna non lacus finibus eleifend. Integer nunc quam, lobortis non velit
      a, congue suscipit sem. Suspendisse fermentum euismod gravida. Cras sed fringilla urna. Phasellus eu lobortis nibh, at placerat urna. Sed aliquet elit felis, eget pretium dolor eleifend sed. Nulla sed facilisis odio. Vivamus molestie tristique sapien
      sit amet pretium. In a condimentum mauris, a efficitur quam.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque ut nulla et tellus venenatis facilisis. Suspendisse at quam ut turpis vulputate aliquet. Morbi luctus cursus malesuada. Aliquam ut lacus in quam rhoncus rhoncus. Aliquam vitae lacinia sapien. Aliquam erat lorem, bibendum ut posuere at,
      faucibus in nibh. Cras lobortis risus quis scelerisque sollicitudin. Aliquam fringilla placerat tortor, ut suscipit ipsum ultrices eget. Nunc ex magna, finibus in lectus vel, placerat commodo mauris. Donec in mi et enim vehicula dictum ut ut odio.
      Morbi mi lectus, eleifend eget varius et, varius at nisl. Donec vitae gravida felis. Nullam condimentum, est a porttitor aliquam, orci diam placerat risus, condimentum tempor dui felis quis purus. Donec scelerisque sollicitudin rutrum. Vestibulum
      ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
    <p>Phasellus lobortis quam leo, ut pretium tortor gravida lacinia. Integer bibendum ut lacus ac facilisis. Sed dignissim diam dolor, ac placerat mauris efficitur nec. Vivamus eleifend, odio eget posuere bibendum, libero diam ultricies nisi, vitae ultrices
      mauris augue ullamcorper justo. Praesent porttitor ultricies rutrum. Ut vel volutpat turpis, non blandit ex. Cras vulputate tincidunt eros eu iaculis.</p>
    <p>Cras ullamcorper cursus erat, ac maximus augue faucibus non. Vestibulum at lectus eu massa convallis tristique. Etiam venenatis ligula a aliquam accumsan. Pellentesque ac venenatis est, sed interdum felis. Donec scelerisque porta tortor, eu ultricies
      est faucibus vel. Ut sit amet libero ac mi vehicula elementum. Etiam vel pulvinar nunc, id imperdiet orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque rhoncus finibus arcu eu venenatis. Morbi
      viverra orci at ipsum suscipit, eu tristique arcu laoreet.</p>
    <p>Cras ultrices non quam ultricies fringilla. Sed eu dolor quam. Quisque leo lorem, rhoncus a dignissim eu, sagittis vel ante. Maecenas purus purus, vestibulum sed ante eu, laoreet ultrices metus. Donec ut nulla diam. Vestibulum vestibulum feugiat ex
      non viverra. Nullam nec posuere arcu. Etiam viverra fringilla sem vel malesuada. Vestibulum in ex vitae metus feugiat efficitur vel eget purus. Aenean accumsan magna dignissim maximus tristique. Cras vestibulum, turpis quis scelerisque fringilla,
      metus erat varius tortor, quis vulputate erat massa et diam. Suspendisse ullamcorper mattis porttitor. Quisque mattis et lectus at pharetra. Morbi tristique arcu sit amet tellus laoreet mollis.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis porttitor quis justo vitae suscipit. Aliquam ac felis eleifend, pharetra turpis malesuada, mattis odio. Morbi semper diam id est vestibulum, non pulvinar
      diam faucibus. Fusce dolor tortor, viverra eget malesuada sit amet, posuere sed tellus. Sed aliquet condimentum est, at finibus justo interdum a. Nam vel justo urna. Donec id magna non lacus finibus eleifend. Integer nunc quam, lobortis non velit
      a, congue suscipit sem. Suspendisse fermentum euismod gravida. Cras sed fringilla urna. Phasellus eu lobortis nibh, at placerat urna. Sed aliquet elit felis, eget pretium dolor eleifend sed. Nulla sed facilisis odio. Vivamus molestie tristique sapien
      sit amet pretium. In a condimentum mauris, a efficitur quam.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque ut nulla et tellus venenatis facilisis. Suspendisse at quam ut turpis vulputate aliquet. Morbi luctus cursus malesuada. Aliquam ut lacus in quam rhoncus rhoncus. Aliquam vitae lacinia sapien. Aliquam erat lorem, bibendum ut posuere at,
      faucibus in nibh. Cras lobortis risus quis scelerisque sollicitudin. Aliquam fringilla placerat tortor, ut suscipit ipsum ultrices eget. Nunc ex magna, finibus in lectus vel, placerat commodo mauris. Donec in mi et enim vehicula dictum ut ut odio.
      Morbi mi lectus, eleifend eget varius et, varius at nisl. Donec vitae gravida felis. Nullam condimentum, est a porttitor aliquam, orci diam placerat risus, condimentum tempor dui felis quis purus. Donec scelerisque sollicitudin rutrum. Vestibulum
      ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
    <p>Phasellus lobortis quam leo, ut pretium tortor gravida lacinia. Integer bibendum ut lacus ac facilisis. Sed dignissim diam dolor, ac placerat mauris efficitur nec. Vivamus eleifend, odio eget posuere bibendum, libero diam ultricies nisi, vitae ultrices
      mauris augue ullamcorper justo. Praesent porttitor ultricies rutrum. Ut vel volutpat turpis, non blandit ex. Cras vulputate tincidunt eros eu iaculis.</p>
    <p>Cras ullamcorper cursus erat, ac maximus augue faucibus non. Vestibulum at lectus eu massa convallis tristique. Etiam venenatis ligula a aliquam accumsan. Pellentesque ac venenatis est, sed interdum felis. Donec scelerisque porta tortor, eu ultricies
      est faucibus vel. Ut sit amet libero ac mi vehicula elementum. Etiam vel pulvinar nunc, id imperdiet orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque rhoncus finibus arcu eu venenatis. Morbi
      viverra orci at ipsum suscipit, eu tristique arcu laoreet.</p>
    <p>Cras ultrices non quam ultricies fringilla. Sed eu dolor quam. Quisque leo lorem, rhoncus a dignissim eu, sagittis vel ante. Maecenas purus purus, vestibulum sed ante eu, laoreet ultrices metus. Donec ut nulla diam. Vestibulum vestibulum feugiat ex
      non viverra. Nullam nec posuere arcu. Etiam viverra fringilla sem vel malesuada. Vestibulum in ex vitae metus feugiat efficitur vel eget purus. Aenean accumsan magna dignissim maximus tristique. Cras vestibulum, turpis quis scelerisque fringilla,
      metus erat varius tortor, quis vulputate erat massa et diam. Suspendisse ullamcorper mattis porttitor. Quisque mattis et lectus at pharetra. Morbi tristique arcu sit amet tellus laoreet mollis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Standard Repeat

You could also do a standard repeating image for the background:

```css
html {}

body {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/850x850") repeat;
}

h1,
p {
  color: #333;
}

#wrapper,
#content,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Background Stuff &amp; Things</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis porttitor quis justo vitae suscipit. Aliquam ac felis eleifend, pharetra turpis malesuada, mattis odio. Morbi semper diam id est vestibulum, non pulvinar
      diam faucibus. Fusce dolor tortor, viverra eget malesuada sit amet, posuere sed tellus. Sed aliquet condimentum est, at finibus justo interdum a. Nam vel justo urna. Donec id magna non lacus finibus eleifend. Integer nunc quam, lobortis non velit
      a, congue suscipit sem. Suspendisse fermentum euismod gravida. Cras sed fringilla urna. Phasellus eu lobortis nibh, at placerat urna. Sed aliquet elit felis, eget pretium dolor eleifend sed. Nulla sed facilisis odio. Vivamus molestie tristique sapien
      sit amet pretium. In a condimentum mauris, a efficitur quam.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque ut nulla et tellus venenatis facilisis. Suspendisse at quam ut turpis vulputate aliquet. Morbi luctus cursus malesuada. Aliquam ut lacus in quam rhoncus rhoncus. Aliquam vitae lacinia sapien. Aliquam erat lorem, bibendum ut posuere at,
      faucibus in nibh. Cras lobortis risus quis scelerisque sollicitudin. Aliquam fringilla placerat tortor, ut suscipit ipsum ultrices eget. Nunc ex magna, finibus in lectus vel, placerat commodo mauris. Donec in mi et enim vehicula dictum ut ut odio.
      Morbi mi lectus, eleifend eget varius et, varius at nisl. Donec vitae gravida felis. Nullam condimentum, est a porttitor aliquam, orci diam placerat risus, condimentum tempor dui felis quis purus. Donec scelerisque sollicitudin rutrum. Vestibulum
      ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
    <p>Phasellus lobortis quam leo, ut pretium tortor gravida lacinia. Integer bibendum ut lacus ac facilisis. Sed dignissim diam dolor, ac placerat mauris efficitur nec. Vivamus eleifend, odio eget posuere bibendum, libero diam ultricies nisi, vitae ultrices
      mauris augue ullamcorper justo. Praesent porttitor ultricies rutrum. Ut vel volutpat turpis, non blandit ex. Cras vulputate tincidunt eros eu iaculis.</p>
    <p>Cras ullamcorper cursus erat, ac maximus augue faucibus non. Vestibulum at lectus eu massa convallis tristique. Etiam venenatis ligula a aliquam accumsan. Pellentesque ac venenatis est, sed interdum felis. Donec scelerisque porta tortor, eu ultricies
      est faucibus vel. Ut sit amet libero ac mi vehicula elementum. Etiam vel pulvinar nunc, id imperdiet orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque rhoncus finibus arcu eu venenatis. Morbi
      viverra orci at ipsum suscipit, eu tristique arcu laoreet.</p>
    <p>Cras ultrices non quam ultricies fringilla. Sed eu dolor quam. Quisque leo lorem, rhoncus a dignissim eu, sagittis vel ante. Maecenas purus purus, vestibulum sed ante eu, laoreet ultrices metus. Donec ut nulla diam. Vestibulum vestibulum feugiat ex
      non viverra. Nullam nec posuere arcu. Etiam viverra fringilla sem vel malesuada. Vestibulum in ex vitae metus feugiat efficitur vel eget purus. Aenean accumsan magna dignissim maximus tristique. Cras vestibulum, turpis quis scelerisque fringilla,
      metus erat varius tortor, quis vulputate erat massa et diam. Suspendisse ullamcorper mattis porttitor. Quisque mattis et lectus at pharetra. Morbi tristique arcu sit amet tellus laoreet mollis.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis porttitor quis justo vitae suscipit. Aliquam ac felis eleifend, pharetra turpis malesuada, mattis odio. Morbi semper diam id est vestibulum, non pulvinar
      diam faucibus. Fusce dolor tortor, viverra eget malesuada sit amet, posuere sed tellus. Sed aliquet condimentum est, at finibus justo interdum a. Nam vel justo urna. Donec id magna non lacus finibus eleifend. Integer nunc quam, lobortis non velit
      a, congue suscipit sem. Suspendisse fermentum euismod gravida. Cras sed fringilla urna. Phasellus eu lobortis nibh, at placerat urna. Sed aliquet elit felis, eget pretium dolor eleifend sed. Nulla sed facilisis odio. Vivamus molestie tristique sapien
      sit amet pretium. In a condimentum mauris, a efficitur quam.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque ut nulla et tellus venenatis facilisis. Suspendisse at quam ut turpis vulputate aliquet. Morbi luctus cursus malesuada. Aliquam ut lacus in quam rhoncus rhoncus. Aliquam vitae lacinia sapien. Aliquam erat lorem, bibendum ut posuere at,
      faucibus in nibh. Cras lobortis risus quis scelerisque sollicitudin. Aliquam fringilla placerat tortor, ut suscipit ipsum ultrices eget. Nunc ex magna, finibus in lectus vel, placerat commodo mauris. Donec in mi et enim vehicula dictum ut ut odio.
      Morbi mi lectus, eleifend eget varius et, varius at nisl. Donec vitae gravida felis. Nullam condimentum, est a porttitor aliquam, orci diam placerat risus, condimentum tempor dui felis quis purus. Donec scelerisque sollicitudin rutrum. Vestibulum
      ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
    <p>Phasellus lobortis quam leo, ut pretium tortor gravida lacinia. Integer bibendum ut lacus ac facilisis. Sed dignissim diam dolor, ac placerat mauris efficitur nec. Vivamus eleifend, odio eget posuere bibendum, libero diam ultricies nisi, vitae ultrices
      mauris augue ullamcorper justo. Praesent porttitor ultricies rutrum. Ut vel volutpat turpis, non blandit ex. Cras vulputate tincidunt eros eu iaculis.</p>
    <p>Cras ullamcorper cursus erat, ac maximus augue faucibus non. Vestibulum at lectus eu massa convallis tristique. Etiam venenatis ligula a aliquam accumsan. Pellentesque ac venenatis est, sed interdum felis. Donec scelerisque porta tortor, eu ultricies
      est faucibus vel. Ut sit amet libero ac mi vehicula elementum. Etiam vel pulvinar nunc, id imperdiet orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque rhoncus finibus arcu eu venenatis. Morbi
      viverra orci at ipsum suscipit, eu tristique arcu laoreet.</p>
    <p>Cras ultrices non quam ultricies fringilla. Sed eu dolor quam. Quisque leo lorem, rhoncus a dignissim eu, sagittis vel ante. Maecenas purus purus, vestibulum sed ante eu, laoreet ultrices metus. Donec ut nulla diam. Vestibulum vestibulum feugiat ex
      non viverra. Nullam nec posuere arcu. Etiam viverra fringilla sem vel malesuada. Vestibulum in ex vitae metus feugiat efficitur vel eget purus. Aenean accumsan magna dignissim maximus tristique. Cras vestibulum, turpis quis scelerisque fringilla,
      metus erat varius tortor, quis vulputate erat massa et diam. Suspendisse ullamcorper mattis porttitor. Quisque mattis et lectus at pharetra. Morbi tristique arcu sit amet tellus laoreet mollis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Fixed Background

I don't know, are you trying to achieve a fixed background?

```css
html {}

body {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/850x850") repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

h1,
p {
  color: #333;
}

#wrapper,
#content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Background Stuff &amp; Things</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis porttitor quis justo vitae suscipit. Aliquam ac felis eleifend, pharetra turpis malesuada, mattis odio. Morbi semper diam id est vestibulum, non pulvinar
      diam faucibus. Fusce dolor tortor, viverra eget malesuada sit amet, posuere sed tellus. Sed aliquet condimentum est, at finibus justo interdum a. Nam vel justo urna. Donec id magna non lacus finibus eleifend. Integer nunc quam, lobortis non velit
      a, congue suscipit sem. Suspendisse fermentum euismod gravida. Cras sed fringilla urna. Phasellus eu lobortis nibh, at placerat urna. Sed aliquet elit felis, eget pretium dolor eleifend sed. Nulla sed facilisis odio. Vivamus molestie tristique sapien
      sit amet pretium. In a condimentum mauris, a efficitur quam.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque ut nulla et tellus venenatis facilisis. Suspendisse at quam ut turpis vulputate aliquet. Morbi luctus cursus malesuada. Aliquam ut lacus in quam rhoncus rhoncus. Aliquam vitae lacinia sapien. Aliquam erat lorem, bibendum ut posuere at,
      faucibus in nibh. Cras lobortis risus quis scelerisque sollicitudin. Aliquam fringilla placerat tortor, ut suscipit ipsum ultrices eget. Nunc ex magna, finibus in lectus vel, placerat commodo mauris. Donec in mi et enim vehicula dictum ut ut odio.
      Morbi mi lectus, eleifend eget varius et, varius at nisl. Donec vitae gravida felis. Nullam condimentum, est a porttitor aliquam, orci diam placerat risus, condimentum tempor dui felis quis purus. Donec scelerisque sollicitudin rutrum. Vestibulum
      ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
    <p>Phasellus lobortis quam leo, ut pretium tortor gravida lacinia. Integer bibendum ut lacus ac facilisis. Sed dignissim diam dolor, ac placerat mauris efficitur nec. Vivamus eleifend, odio eget posuere bibendum, libero diam ultricies nisi, vitae ultrices
      mauris augue ullamcorper justo. Praesent porttitor ultricies rutrum. Ut vel volutpat turpis, non blandit ex. Cras vulputate tincidunt eros eu iaculis.</p>
    <p>Cras ullamcorper cursus erat, ac maximus augue faucibus non. Vestibulum at lectus eu massa convallis tristique. Etiam venenatis ligula a aliquam accumsan. Pellentesque ac venenatis est, sed interdum felis. Donec scelerisque porta tortor, eu ultricies
      est faucibus vel. Ut sit amet libero ac mi vehicula elementum. Etiam vel pulvinar nunc, id imperdiet orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque rhoncus finibus arcu eu venenatis. Morbi
      viverra orci at ipsum suscipit, eu tristique arcu laoreet.</p>
    <p>Cras ultrices non quam ultricies fringilla. Sed eu dolor quam. Quisque leo lorem, rhoncus a dignissim eu, sagittis vel ante. Maecenas purus purus, vestibulum sed ante eu, laoreet ultrices metus. Donec ut nulla diam. Vestibulum vestibulum feugiat ex
      non viverra. Nullam nec posuere arcu. Etiam viverra fringilla sem vel malesuada. Vestibulum in ex vitae metus feugiat efficitur vel eget purus. Aenean accumsan magna dignissim maximus tristique. Cras vestibulum, turpis quis scelerisque fringilla,
      metus erat varius tortor, quis vulputate erat massa et diam. Suspendisse ullamcorper mattis porttitor. Quisque mattis et lectus at pharetra. Morbi tristique arcu sit amet tellus laoreet mollis.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis porttitor quis justo vitae suscipit. Aliquam ac felis eleifend, pharetra turpis malesuada, mattis odio. Morbi semper diam id est vestibulum, non pulvinar
      diam faucibus. Fusce dolor tortor, viverra eget malesuada sit amet, posuere sed tellus. Sed aliquet condimentum est, at finibus justo interdum a. Nam vel justo urna. Donec id magna non lacus finibus eleifend. Integer nunc quam, lobortis non velit
      a, congue suscipit sem. Suspendisse fermentum euismod gravida. Cras sed fringilla urna. Phasellus eu lobortis nibh, at placerat urna. Sed aliquet elit felis, eget pretium dolor eleifend sed. Nulla sed facilisis odio. Vivamus molestie tristique sapien
      sit amet pretium. In a condimentum mauris, a efficitur quam.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque ut nulla et tellus venenatis facilisis. Suspendisse at quam ut turpis vulputate aliquet. Morbi luctus cursus malesuada. Aliquam ut lacus in quam rhoncus rhoncus. Aliquam vitae lacinia sapien. Aliquam erat lorem, bibendum ut posuere at,
      faucibus in nibh. Cras lobortis risus quis scelerisque sollicitudin. Aliquam fringilla placerat tortor, ut suscipit ipsum ultrices eget. Nunc ex magna, finibus in lectus vel, placerat commodo mauris. Donec in mi et enim vehicula dictum ut ut odio.
      Morbi mi lectus, eleifend eget varius et, varius at nisl. Donec vitae gravida felis. Nullam condimentum, est a porttitor aliquam, orci diam placerat risus, condimentum tempor dui felis quis purus. Donec scelerisque sollicitudin rutrum. Vestibulum
      ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
    <p>Phasellus lobortis quam leo, ut pretium tortor gravida lacinia. Integer bibendum ut lacus ac facilisis. Sed dignissim diam dolor, ac placerat mauris efficitur nec. Vivamus eleifend, odio eget posuere bibendum, libero diam ultricies nisi, vitae ultrices
      mauris augue ullamcorper justo. Praesent porttitor ultricies rutrum. Ut vel volutpat turpis, non blandit ex. Cras vulputate tincidunt eros eu iaculis.</p>
    <p>Cras ullamcorper cursus erat, ac maximus augue faucibus non. Vestibulum at lectus eu massa convallis tristique. Etiam venenatis ligula a aliquam accumsan. Pellentesque ac venenatis est, sed interdum felis. Donec scelerisque porta tortor, eu ultricies
      est faucibus vel. Ut sit amet libero ac mi vehicula elementum. Etiam vel pulvinar nunc, id imperdiet orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque rhoncus finibus arcu eu venenatis. Morbi
      viverra orci at ipsum suscipit, eu tristique arcu laoreet.</p>
    <p>Cras ultrices non quam ultricies fringilla. Sed eu dolor quam. Quisque leo lorem, rhoncus a dignissim eu, sagittis vel ante. Maecenas purus purus, vestibulum sed ante eu, laoreet ultrices metus. Donec ut nulla diam. Vestibulum vestibulum feugiat ex
      non viverra. Nullam nec posuere arcu. Etiam viverra fringilla sem vel malesuada. Vestibulum in ex vitae metus feugiat efficitur vel eget purus. Aenean accumsan magna dignissim maximus tristique. Cras vestibulum, turpis quis scelerisque fringilla,
      metus erat varius tortor, quis vulputate erat massa et diam. Suspendisse ullamcorper mattis porttitor. Quisque mattis et lectus at pharetra. Morbi tristique arcu sit amet tellus laoreet mollis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish and why are you using `::before` on the body for the background?

Comment: I need to use the pseudo element as I have another background image under body, that is why.